# script type="module" not console.log anything? in node-fetch

Tags: javascript, http, fetch, node-fetch

I am Using node-fetch for some reason, I do it on simple HTMl and js not npm install. I want to use it with cdn. below attachments, I used this approach and not logging anything.

In html

```
<script type="module" src="module.js"></script>
```

In module.js

```
import nodeFetch from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/node-fetch@3.3.0/+esm';

console.log(nodeFetch)

console.log("asdsad"); // not log anything
```

WHat is the best way to use it with cdn, I confused, and tried to all day.

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in fetch and not node-fetch? Generally speaking, node modules will not work with HTML & browser based code.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you load this page. I have a feeling that node-fetch is not browser friendly and is throwing errors that are preventing you from getting to the console.log lines in your code.

Comment: Yes, I tried with build-in fetch but I have an authentication error unauthenticated. Same Request I used in the js online compiler programiz, it quickly fetches the data in the online compiler. but in vs code, when  I use the fetch method, I get an unauthenticated error, even if pass the correct Token with a header @EpicPuppy613

Answer (score 1):

When I run that code I get the following errors reported in my console:

> Loading failed for the module with source “`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/data-uri-to-buffer@4.0.0/+esm`”. localhost:7007:1:1
>
>  Loading failed for the module with source “`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fetch-blob@3.2.0/+esm`”. localhost:7007:1:1
>
>  Loading failed for the module with source “`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/formdata-polyfill@4.0.10/esm.min.js/+esm`”. localhost:7007:1:1
>
>  Loading failed for the module with source “`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fetch-blob@3.2.0/from.js/+esm`”.

Since the dependencies are failing, the script aborts before reaching `console.log`.

`node-fetch` doesn't appear to be a module designed to run client-side in a web browser!